# Trying to find first outlet in on a circuit, but for each one, removing one leaves the other one powered

Tags: wiring, gfci

I have a multi-outlet circuit (confirmed that all turn off when I flip the same breaker).

I had always thought the way to find out which was first in the circuit was to remove the one you are guessing is first and see if the others no longer have power. I removed the first one and the other one stayed on. So then I added that first one back in and removed the second one. But the first one kept power!

So I am confused here. Shouldn't one be earlier in the circuit than the other? Or is it possible that they branch in such a way that they are in "parallel" of sorts that they don't rely on each other?

Thank you!

Comment: What do the wires look like when you remove an outlet? What do they look like with the outlet installed? Show pictures.

Comment: Both outlets include both line and load (two black two white).  Installed there are two white on one side and two black on the other. I have reinstalled the original outlets, but if if that information is not sufficient I can pull them back out.

Comment: It is likely that they are connected in parallel. A picture would help.

Comment: If you are lucky and get the normal cheap/lazy worker, then it is usually the closest outlet to the panel on that circuit that is first.  Some crazy money bags wackos out there and put the closest as the last, but they are few and far.

Comment: Our outlet wiring from the 1950s has a run of 5 outlets starting in the garage and running through the kitchen and laundry room. In each outlet box, upstream wires enter and have outgoing downstream wires "Western Electric splice" spiral wrapped and soldered (!) on a few inches before the ends. The upstream wire ends are then secured to the outlet terminals. Any outlet or outlet connection failure does not affect the upstream or downstream outlets.

Comment: @crip659 is right that normally the outlet closest to the panel is first and so forth. You can verify this by measuring the voltage at each outlet. The further the outlet from the panel, the longer the wire run and so the greater the resistance. That will produce a slight voltage drop that will be larger for the more downstream outlets.

Comment: @Armand   I don't think most of the meters regular homeowners have are that good to tell for normal house size/outlet spacing.  Some of them even change the reading if you look at them funny.

Comment: @crip659 Yes, could be. I actually used an (expensive!) Ideal circuit analyzer on my house and welcomed the extra info like voltage drop under load and impedance, but I've not tried a normal multimeter.

Comment: As mentioned above multiple times, photos of the wiring/outlet would really help, and might get you an answer more specific to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

### Tree Topology is required for *cabling*

A cable is several wires grouped or wrapped in a sheath.

AC mains power requires **cabling** is done in a Tree Topology.  Meaning unlimited branches are permitted, but different branches are not allowed to re-connect to each other, forming a loop.  So if you diagrammed your cable diagram in MS-Paint, and used the "paint bucket" tool on any empty space in the canvas, it must fill the entire canvas.

We're in electronics stackexchange, so I'll lede with **Why a tree toplogy?**  Current flows in loops. Electrical codes require that in any cable, current flow be equal and opposite - thus any current which flows up a "branch of the tree" must come back that same branch (not hop to another branch and return via a different route).

Why is "Equal and opposite" required?  Because AC power throws a considerable *dynamic* magnetic field - after all, that's how transformers work.  Get it?  It's not "a refrigerator magnet" like in DC.  It's "a refrigerator magnet that is spinning".  As long as wires are grouped, these magnetic fields will substantially cancel each other out. If not, it will induce heating and vibration into nearby metallic things, including the wires themselves. Vibration is a problem because copper and aluminum *do not have a fatigue limit* so all movement adds to fatigue. The wire cracks, the cross section is reduced so you get localized heating, or it breaks entirely and you get series arcing, making spectacular amounts of heat and starting fires.  Indeed North America now mandates Arc Fault Circuit Interruptors (AFCI) which have a digital signal processor "listening" for that "crinkle crunch" of arcing.

### Implementation of Tree Topology

Of course... a "vine" is one type of "tree".  A very boring one lol.

In some countries, "vine" is used simply because **the cheap** (50 cent) receptacles provide double terminals (one for "power coming in" and the other for "power going onward").  Of course, the **spec grade** ($2.50) receptacles provide *quad* terminals, making tee or plus splits easy.

Use of the receptacle to splice is only a convenience; "pigtail" splices are preferred, and have no limit - one popular splice block has **eight** ports.  Realistically you hit "box fill" limits, but this is Electronics StackExchange, and that's boring LOL.